# issue on my recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I'm trying to show up recyclerview and retrieve data from firebase but I got problem after adding images which I saved on firebase storage. It closed after scrolling. I have another recyclerview which is using the same database but it doesnt have issue. can you give me solution for this?

AllLaundries.java

```
   package com.example.rizkafs.laundrize;

            import android.content.Context;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
            import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.ImageView;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
            import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
            import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
            import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
            import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
            import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
            import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
            import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

            /**
             * Created by Abi FS on 29.5.17.
             */
            public class AllLaundries extends AppCompatActivity {

                private Context context;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_laundries);
                    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("places");
                    Query queryRef = myRef.orderByChild("jenis").equalTo("Laundry Kiloan");
                    RecyclerView rvView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
                    rvView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    rvView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

                    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataLaundry, DataViewHolder> recyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataLaundry, DataViewHolder>(
                            DataLaundry.class,
                            R.layout.laundry_card,
                            DataViewHolder.class,
                            queryRef
                    ) {
                        @Override
                        protected void populateViewHolder(DataViewHolder viewHolder, DataLaundry model, int position) {
                            viewHolder.setNamaTempat(model.getNama());
                            viewHolder.setAlamat(model.getAlamat());
                            viewHolder.setJenis(model.getJenis());
                            viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage_placeholder(), AllLaundries.this);
                        }
                    };
                    rvView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                }

                public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                    View mView;
                    TextView txt_namaTempat;
                    TextView txt_alamat;
                    TextView txt_jenis;
                    ImageView imageView;

                    public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
                        super(itemView);
                        mView = itemView;
                        txt_namaTempat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_judul);
                        txt_alamat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alamat);
                        txt_jenis = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.jenis);
                        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    }

                    public void setNamaTempat(String namaTempat) {
                        txt_namaTempat.setText(namaTempat);
                    }

                    public void setAlamat(String alamat){
                        txt_alamat.setText(alamat);
                    }

                    public void setJenis(String jenis) {
                        txt_jenis.setText(jenis);
                    }

                    public void setImage(String image, Context context) {
                        Log.d("DEBUG_", "Load image ");
                        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://laundrize-68cee.appspot.com/");
                        StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child(image);
                        Glide.with(context)
                                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                                .load(pathReference)
                                .into(imageView);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Android Monitor

```
        06-19 00:30:35.736 14636-15761/com.example.rizkafs.laundrize E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseStorage-Download-1
                                                                           Process: com.example.rizkafs.laundrize, PID: 14636
                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzax(Z)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.example.rizkafs.laundrize-1/base.apk)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.onCanceled(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzf(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Its difficult to follow along with your entire activities code. Asking multiple smaller specific questions are easier to answer and give you a higher chance of someone being able to help you

Comment: do all your models in your firebase database have an image placeholder?

Comment: I've been searching that I was wrong typing the code but it keep showing error

Comment: You have a version mismatch in your dependencies

Comment: [Fix up your dependencies using `ext {}` section](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/95/gradle-for-android/2911/centralizing-dependencies-via-dependencies-gradle-file#t=201706181756370469707)