# RecyclerView with Firebase Database and Storage Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I'm trying to show up recyclerview and retrieve data from firebase but I got problem after adding images which I saved on firebase storage. It closed after scrolling. I have another recyclerview which is using the same database but it doesnt have issue. can you give me solution for this?

AllLaundries.java

```
            package com.example.rizkafs.laundrize;

            import android.content.Context;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
            import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.ImageView;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
            import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
            import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
            import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
            import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
            import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
            import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
            import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

            /**
             * Created by Abi FS on 29.5.17.
             */
            public class AllLaundries extends AppCompatActivity {

                private Context context;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_laundries);
                    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("places");
                    Query queryRef = myRef.orderByChild("jenis").equalTo("Laundry Kiloan");
                    RecyclerView rvView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
                    rvView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    rvView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

                    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataLaundry, DataViewHolder> recyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataLaundry, DataViewHolder>(
                            DataLaundry.class,
                            R.layout.laundry_card,
                            DataViewHolder.class,
                            queryRef
                    ) {
                        @Override
                        protected void populateViewHolder(DataViewHolder viewHolder, DataLaundry model, int position) {
                            viewHolder.setNamaTempat(model.getNama());
                            viewHolder.setAlamat(model.getAlamat());
                            viewHolder.setJenis(model.getJenis());
                            viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage_placeholder(), AllLaundries.this);
                        }
                    };
                    rvView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                }

                public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                    View mView;
                    TextView txt_namaTempat;
                    TextView txt_alamat;
                    TextView txt_jenis;
                    ImageView imageView;

                    public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
                        super(itemView);
                        mView = itemView;
                        txt_namaTempat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_judul);
                        txt_alamat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alamat);
                        txt_jenis = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.jenis);
                        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    }

                    public void setNamaTempat(String namaTempat) {
                        txt_namaTempat.setText(namaTempat);
                    }

                    public void setAlamat(String alamat){
                        txt_alamat.setText(alamat);
                    }

                    public void setJenis(String jenis) {
                        txt_jenis.setText(jenis);
                    }

                    public void setImage(String image, Context context) {
                        Log.d("DEBUG_", "Load image ");
                        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://laundrize-68cee.appspot.com/");
                        StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child(image);
                        Glide.with(context)
                                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                                .load(pathReference)
                                .into(imageView);
                    }
                }
            }
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
 package com.example.rizkafs.laundrize;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
    import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
    import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
    import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by Herdi_WORK on 15.09.16.
     */
    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private List<DataLaundry> rvData;
        private Context context;

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataLaundry> rvData) {
            this.rvData = rvData;
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            // di tutorial ini kita hanya menggunakan data String untuk tiap item
            CardView cv;
            public TextView nama;
            public TextView alamat;
            public TextView jenis;
            public ImageView imageVIew;

            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                cv = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                nama = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_judul);
                alamat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.alamat);
                jenis = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.jenis);
                imageVIew = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // membuat view baru
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.laundry_card, parent, false);
            // mengeset ukuran view, margin, padding, dan parameter layout lainnya
            context = parent.getContext();
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int i) {
            try {
                // - mengambil elemen dari dataset (ArrayList) pada posisi tertentu
                // - mengeset isi view dengan elemen dari dataset tersebut
                DataLaundry list = rvData.get(i);
                holder.nama.setText(list.getNama());
                holder.alamat.setText(list.getAlamat());
                holder.jenis.setText(list.getJenis());
                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://laundrize-68cee.appspot.com/");
                StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child(list.getImageUrl()[0]);
                Glide.with(context)
                        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                        .load(pathReference)
                        .into(holder.imageVIew);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            // menghitung ukuran dataset / jumlah data yang ditampilkan di RecyclerView
            return rvData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }
    }
```

DataLaundry.java(My Model)

```
    package com.example.rizkafs.laundrize;

    import android.os.Parcel;
    import android.os.Parcelable;

    /**
     * Created by Abi FS on 6/3/2017.
     */

    public class DataLaundry implements Parcelable {

        String nama;
        String alamat;
        String jenis;
        String harga;
        String jamOperasi;
        String no_telp;
        String latitude;
        String longitude;
        String image_url[];
        String image_placeholder;

        public DataLaundry() {
        }

        public DataLaundry(String latitude, String longitude, String nama, String alamat,
                           String jenis, String harga, String jamOperasi, String no_telp,
                           String image_url[], String image_placeholder) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.nama = nama;
            this.alamat = alamat;
            this.jenis = jenis;
            this.harga = harga;
            this.jamOperasi = jamOperasi;
            this.no_telp = no_telp;
            this.image_url = image_url;
            this.image_placeholder = image_placeholder;
        }

        protected DataLaundry(Parcel in) {
            nama = in.readString();
            alamat = in.readString();
            jenis = in.readString();
            harga = in.readString();
            jamOperasi = in.readString();
            no_telp = in.readString();
            latitude = in.readString();
            longitude = in.readString();
            image_url = in.createStringArray();
            image_placeholder = in.readString();
        }

        public static final Creator<DataLaundry> CREATOR = new Creator<DataLaundry>() {
            @Override
            public DataLaundry createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new DataLaundry(in);
            }

            @Override
            public DataLaundry[] newArray(int size) {
                return new DataLaundry[size];
            }
        };

        public String getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }

        public String getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public String getNama() {
            return nama;
        }

        public void setNama(String nama) {
            this.nama = nama;
        }

        public String getAlamat() {
            return alamat;
        }

        public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
            this.alamat = alamat;
        }

        public String getJenis() {
            return jenis;
        }

        public void setJenis(String jenis) {
            this.jenis = jenis;
        }

        public String getHarga() {
            return harga;
        }

        public void setHarga(String harga) {
            this.harga = harga;
        }

        public String getJamOperasi() {
            return jamOperasi;
        }

        public void setJamOperasi(String jamOperasi) {
            this.jamOperasi = jamOperasi;
        }

        public String getImage_placeholder() {
            return image_placeholder;
        }

        public void setImage_placeholder(String image_placeholder) {
            this.image_placeholder = image_placeholder;
        }

        public String getNoTelp() {
            return no_telp;
        }

        public void setNoTelp(String no_telp) {
            this.no_telp = no_telp;
        }

        public String[] getImageUrl() {
            return image_url;
        }

        public void setImageUrl(String[] image_url) {
            this.image_url = image_url;
        }



        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(nama);
            dest.writeString(alamat);
            dest.writeString(jenis);
            dest.writeString(harga);
            dest.writeString(jamOperasi);
            dest.writeString(no_telp);
            dest.writeString(latitude);
            dest.writeString(longitude);
            dest.writeStringArray(image_url);
            dest.writeString(image_placeholder);
        }
    }
```

And Here is the Error

```
    06-19 00:30:35.736 14636-15761/com.example.rizkafs.laundrize E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseStorage-Download-1
                                                                           Process: com.example.rizkafs.laundrize, PID: 14636
                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzax(Z)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.example.rizkafs.laundrize-1/base.apk)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.onCanceled(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzf(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: In all previous cases I've seen this, it was caused by using different versions of Firebase and Google Play Services. Please ensure that they're all the same version in your build.gradle.

Comment: Don't post the same question multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617345/issue-on-my-recyclerview